# How to make, that the Rover drives to the left and stop

Tags: arduino, esp32

at the moment I'm using an L298 Motor Driver, an ultrasonic Sensor, and an ESP32. The goal is when the Ultrasonic Sensor(which is at the front of the Rover) detects an object, the Rover drives to the left and stops.
The problem is, that when the Sensor detects an object, the rover only stops without moving to the left. Otherwise, if I delete the Stop part of the code, my rover goes to the left. However, I do not know how I make, that he does both commands.

```
// defines Sensor pins

#define trigPin 12
#define echoPin 13

//Define Motor pins
#define motorIn3  16 //Input 3
#define motorIn1  17 //Input 1
#define motorIn4  18 //Input 4
#define motorIn2  19 //Input 2

// defines variables
long duration;
int distance;

// define ActivateDistance
double activateDistance = 20;

void setup() 
{
  // Sets the trigPin as an Output
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); 
  // Sets the echoPin as an Input
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); 

  // sets the Motorpins  as outputs:
  pinMode(motorIn1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorIn2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorIn3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorIn4, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication

}

void loop() 
{

  //Moving Motor forward
  digitalWrite(motorIn2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorIn4, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorIn3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorIn1, LOW); 

  // Clears the trigPin
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);

 // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(5);
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

 // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
 duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

 // Calculating the distance
 distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;


//when the distance is under 20, the motor should drives to the left and stopps.
 if (distance <= activateDistance)
 {
  //for loop using that the motor drives a specific amount to the left
  for(int i = 0; i<5;i++)
  {
 //Motor drives to left
  digitalWrite(motorIn1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorIn2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorIn3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorIn4, LOW);
//After drives to left, the motor should stop.
    if(i == 4)
    {  
      //Moves forward 
      digitalWrite(motorIn2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(motorIn4, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(motorIn3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motorIn1, LOW); 
      delay(1000);
      //Motor Stops.
      digitalWrite(motorIn1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motorIn2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motorIn3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motorIn4, LOW); 
    }
  }

 }
  delay(1000);
}
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Please comment a bit your code, it is impossible to know what motor is doing what (going forward or turn), and what do you expect each lines to do.

Comment: Thank you, for answering, I comment more each line, so that you people know what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to rewrite your code with functions that each one has its own purpose. This will give you more insight into what is going on and what the problem is. For example, you can create a function that calculates the distance and check it in your main loop, or creating a vehicle forward function with a duration as an argument.

Second, when you set your motor pins you need to put some delay to give enough time to your vehicle to move.

I rewrite your code with some functions and put some prints, just remember to calibrate the timings for better performance.

```
// defines Sensor pins

#define trigPin 12
#define echoPin 13

//Define Motor pins
#define motorIn3 16 //Input 3
#define motorIn1 17 //Input 1
#define motorIn4 18 //Input 4
#define motorIn2 19 //Input 2

// defines variables
long duration;
int distance;

// define ActivateDistance
const int activateDistance = 20;

void setup()
{
    // Sets the trigPin as an Output
    pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
    // Sets the echoPin as an Input
    pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
    // sets the Motorpins  as outputs:
    pinMode(motorIn1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motorIn2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motorIn3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motorIn4, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication
}

void stop()
{
    // stop motor without duration
    Serial.println("STOP");
    digitalWrite(motorIn1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorIn2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorIn3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorIn4, LOW);
}

void left(int duration)
{
    //Motor goes to left
    Serial.println("LEFT");
    digitalWrite(motorIn1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorIn2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorIn3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorIn4, LOW);
    delay(duration);
    stop();
}

void forward(int duration)
{
    //Motor goes forward
    Serial.println("FORWARD");
    digitalWrite(motorIn2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorIn4, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorIn3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorIn1, LOW);
    delay(duration);
    stop();
}

long get_distance(void)
{
    //get distance from sensor
    // Clears the trigPin
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
    // Calculating the distance
    distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;
    return distance;
}

void loop()
{
    // check sensor
    if (get_distance() <= activateDistance)
    {
        Serial.println("Found an Obstacle!!!");
        // go left for 1 second
        left(1000);
        // go forward for 1 second
        forward(1000);
    }
    else
        // go forward for 1 second
        forward(1000);
}
```

Comment: Hey and thanks for answering. I tried using our code and it works successfully.

Answer (score 1):

There is no delay at all after you instructed the Rover drives to the left, thus the four first times in the `for(int i = 0; i<5;i++)` will execute very quickly. Maybe **add a delay** there in order for the Rover to have time to complete the turn.

Also I do not understand why you put `if(i == 4)` and the following instruction at the end of the `for loop`: you can put it after the `for` loop and having exactly the same behaviour.

Hope it helps.